# Late 2019 Macbook Air with Intel Core i5 8GB RAM 128 SSD

Tags: macbook-pro, hardware, upgrade, processor, logicboard

I have a late 2019 MacBook air with an Intel Core i5. I REALLY want to upgrade this processor to make the laptop just a bit better. Because I just bought it, I really don't want to get a whole new computer. I was wondering if it is possible to replace the possessor. I have heard that the processor is attached to the logic board so I am open to getting a new logic board. If anyone wants to help me out that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I’m curious what benchmark or operation you have that’s making things CPU bound? I have one of these for work and it screams for me. Very capable mac.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, the processor is soldered. I highly doubt buying a logic board is a good choice. You can't buy it from Apple, so you're stuck with third party options. It's also fairly likely that a working logic board that you want is going to be fairly expensive, maybe even more expensive than just buying a new laptop.

Your best value is sell this mac - perhap helping someone get it set up so they are happy paying full price and then order the gear you want paying the delta in what your sells for and what the new costs.